# $K_{13}$ 3D toroidal cell

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, 3d, integer-lattices

Complete graph $K_7$ can be defined by the following toroidal cell acting on the unit triangular lattice.

```
{{-2,-Sqrt[3]/2},{1/2,Sqrt[3]},{2,Sqrt[3]/2},{-1/2,-Sqrt[3]}}
```

Here's a picture:

[image: K_7]

Is there a defining 3D toroidal cell acting on a unit 3D lattice that gives $K_{13}$?

Comment: I had a think about this but can't even imagine a suitable 3D lattice. To replicate $K_{13}$ we need degree $12$. A cubic lattice won't work because it has degree $6$. None of the other Platonic solids is space-filling and a quick look at space-filling polyhedra didn't suggest an obvious lattice. Am I missing something? Did you have a particular 3D lattice in mind?

Comment: Actually, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral-octahedral_honeycomb looks possible, but I'd still be interested to know if there are other suitable lattices.